# Constant value infront of the Gaussian Process Kernel

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, constants, gaussian-process

I would like to use GP for a surrogate model for my optimization problem. I found a nice example from `scikit learn`, which can be found: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy_targets.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-gpr-noisy-targets-py

I mostly understood the code, however I do not understand this constant value(`1`) [`kernel = 1 * RBF(...)`] before the RBF definition.

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF

kernel = 1 * RBF(length_scale=1.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-2, 1e2))
gaussian_process = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=9)
gaussian_process.fit(X_train, y_train)
gaussian_process.kernel_
```

My x value is a vector with 250 dimensions, because of that I think I need to give the attribute length scale as `length_scale=250`, but what should I do about the `1`?

Comment: Reading the source code of SciPy, it seems like multiplying an RBF by a constant causes all of the values which come out of that RBF to be multiplied by that constant. So it would appear to do nothing. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e047ca08a95862becf40a04fe9d4cd2c98/sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py#L349 That's a very strange example.

Comment: @NickODell - thank yoi! if you would do some testing and show this as an answer, I can accept it!